# syntax error on updating two tables with one trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

hi i'm trying to update two different tables with one trigger but i keep getting syntax error and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'UPDATE specialitys s
>
> JOIN speciality_objects o
>         ON s.id = o.speciality' at line 2

triggers works fine if i just update one table but i cant put them both in one trigger

here is my trigger

```
  DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER after_user_type_or_status_change
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON users
  FOR EACH ROW

  BEGIN
  UPDATE stats s 

  SET

    ee_counter =
      CASE 
        WHEN  NEW.type= 1 THEN ee_counter + 1
        WHEN  NEW.type= 3  && OLD.type = 2 THEN ee_counter + 1
        WHEN  OLD.type= 1  && NEW.type != 3  THEN ee_counter - 1
        ELSE ee_counter 
      END ,

    er_counter =
      CASE 
        WHEN  NEW.type= 2  THEN er_counter + 1
        WHEN  NEW.type= 3  && OLD.type = 1 THEN er_counter + 1
        WHEN  OLD.type= 2  && NEW.type != 3  THEN er_counter - 1
        ELSE er_counter 
      END 

  WHERE
    s.id = 1;
END $$

BEGIN
UPDATE specialitys sp 

JOIN speciality_objects o
      ON sp.id = o.speciality_id

    JOIN users u
      ON o.user_id = u.id

 SET
    counter =
      CASE 
        WHEN  NEW.status = 1 THEN counter + 1
         ELSE counter 
      END 

  WHERE
    sp.id = o.speciality_id ;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `END $$` in the middle is ending the trigger definition. Remove it and the following `BEGIN`.